# Trigger AWS Lambda function from successfully deployed Service Catalog Provisioned Product

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-service-catalog

In this setup, AWS accounts are created by launching a Service Catalog product for each account. After successful product provisioning, the status of the provisioned product changes to "Available". I wanted to capture this status change and trigger a Lambda function each time a provisioned product changes status to Available.

I have investigated AWS Event Bridge, however there are no *Event type* that shows "Provisioned Product Status Change"
[image: Event Type not showing provisioned product status change]

Could someone explain how to specify the event type for Service Catalog Provisioned Products Status Change?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to know what types of events are captured by EventBridge in your operations, you can just set `All Events` and see the results through the process. (I normally use SNS to catch results.)

But I'm afraid I don't think EventBridge won't capture the state change you want to check (because it is not shown on the console). EventBridge only captures normal [APIs for Service Catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/dg/API_ProvisionProduct.html).